# JScrollPane minimum width inside JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

I'm trying out the `JSplitPane` with a couple of scrollable side-by-side `JTable`s.
However I'm experiment a behavior where the `JScrollPane` gets shrinked too much, as per gif.
Notice the **left component**, that besides having a minimum `width` of `250px`, continues shrinking.

[image]

The relevant code is

```
final var objetsTable = new JTable();
final var objectsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(objetsTable);
objectsScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 0));
objectsScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

final var stepsTable = new JTable();
final var stepsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(stepsTable);
stepsScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 0));
stepsScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));

final var splitPane = new JSplitPane();
splitPane.setLeftComponent(objectsScrollPane);
splitPane.setRightComponent(stepsScrollPane);
splitPane.setResizeWeight(1.0);
```

How can I avoid the `JScrollPane`s getting shrinked too much in this case?

Comment: What would you like to happen when both right and left components meet their minimum sizes and the user keeps shrinking?

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @gthanop I'd like the JFrame (or the outer component at least) to stop shrinking.

Comment: Then set the minimum size of the **`JFrame`**. This will make the user unable to continue shrinking.

Comment: @gthanop sure that's the easy way out. But I don't like the idea to set a fixed size for the outermost component. It should be based on the containing lightweight components.

Comment: Good idea @gthanop. OP: that would be [`Window.setMinimumSize(Dimension)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize(java.awt.Dimension)). *"But I don't like the idea to set a fixed size for the outermost component."* It's not a non resizable window, it just has a minimum size.

Comment: @AndrewThompson btw, the JSplitPane calculates when to stop the divider with the component's minimum size, so in this case it's ok to use it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson with fixed size I mean putting pixel integer literals on the minimum size, making it harder to adjust over time.

Comment: *"so in this case it's ok to use it"* The GIF really sells that concept..

Comment: @AndrewThompson if a minimum size for the contained component isn't set the middle divider will be able to be dragged everywhere. When a minimum size is set, the user won't be able to drag it past a certain point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getMinimumSize` called on a `JSplitPane` returns a size which is actually taking into account the minimum size of its left and right `Component`s, plus the divider size. So one way to maybe solve your problem would be to make your `JSplitPane` implement `Scrollable` (in order to make it respect the minimum size of itself) and add it to a `JScrollPane`. This way you can ensure that the minimum size is respected and when the user continues shrinking the `Scrollable` `JSplitPane` past its minimum size, then the scroll bars will show up.

Here is some working code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    
    private static class MyScrollableSplitPane extends JSplitPane implements Scrollable {
        
        private int maxUnitIncrement = 10;
        
        public void setMaxUnitIncrement(final int pixels) {
            maxUnitIncrement = pixels;
        }
        
        public int getMaxUnitIncrement() {
            return maxUnitIncrement;
        }
        
        /**
         * This is being constantly checked by the scroll pane instead of the
         * getPreferredScrollableViewportSize...
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            final Dimension minSz = getMinimumSize(),
                            curSz = getSize();
            curSz.width = Math.max(curSz.width, minSz.width);
            curSz.height = Math.max(curSz.height, minSz.height);
            return curSz;
        }
        
        /**
         * This is only checked once (at the beginning).
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }

        /**
         * Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html .
         */
        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                              int orientation,
                                              int direction) {
            //Get the current position.
            int currentPosition;
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
                currentPosition = visibleRect.x;
            } else {
                currentPosition = visibleRect.y;
            }

            //Return the number of pixels between currentPosition
            //and the nearest tick mark in the indicated direction.
            if (direction < 0) {
                int newPosition = currentPosition -
                                 (currentPosition / maxUnitIncrement)
                                  * maxUnitIncrement;
                return (newPosition == 0) ? maxUnitIncrement : newPosition;
            } else {
                return ((currentPosition / maxUnitIncrement) + 1)
                       * maxUnitIncrement
                       - currentPosition;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html .
         */
        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                               int orientation,
                                               int direction) {
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
                return visibleRect.width - maxUnitIncrement;
            } else {
                return visibleRect.height - maxUnitIncrement;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            final Container parent = getParent();
            return (parent instanceof JViewport) && (getMinimumSize().width < ((JViewport) parent).getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            final Container parent = getParent();
            return (parent instanceof JViewport) && (getMinimumSize().height < ((JViewport) parent).getHeight());
        }
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        
        /*Since I don't add any Components to the 'left' and 'right' panels, I am going to set the
        preferred size of them. This is only for demonstrating the concept. Setting the minimum size
        though is somewhat required by the JSplitPane itself.*/
        
        final JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
        left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        
        final JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        
        final JSplitPane split = new MyScrollableSplitPane();
        split.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN.darker(), 3));
        split.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        split.setLeftComponent(left);
        split.setRightComponent(right);
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyScrollableSplitPane demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(split));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look and a try asap

Comment: This, plus adding `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL/HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` to the outer scroll pane, and `frame.setMinimumSize(split.getMinimumSize())` gets to the result I wanted.

Comment: Try adding both of my edits and look at the result.

Comment: That way you can even remove the `new JScrollPane(split)` if you aren't interested in the frame shrinking and showing scroll bars.

Comment: I am glad you got it working. Note about `frame.setMinimumSize(split.getMinimumSize());`: I think the minimum size of the frame takes into account the title bar and the window borders...

Comment: Yeah I've noticed there is something not perfect but I'll sort it out.